# Bloomberg .NET API CAS Permission Set

Tags: c#, security, bloomberg

I am working on an application which uses the Bloomberg API and to be used via its portal. This is a .NET4.0 app. It fails the security validation, throwing an exception like this:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message='Set connectionId threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '14'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=6
  LinePosition=14
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at Application2.MainView.InitializeComponent()
       at Application2.MainView..ctor()
  InnerException: System.IO.FileLoadException
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'MyCustomDll, Version=1.5.4700.39806, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b55dd9efe817e823' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)
       Source=Application2
       FileName=MyCustomDll, Version=1.5.4700.39806, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b55dd9efe817e823
       StackTrace:
            at Application2.MainView.System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(Int32 connectionId, Object target)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetConnectionId(Object root, Int32 connectionId, Object instance)
       InnerException: System.Security.Policy.PolicyException
            Message=Required permissions cannot be acquired.
            Source=mscorlib
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Boolean checkExecutionPermission)
                 at System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolveCasPolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Int32& securitySpecialFlags, Boolean checkExecutionPermission)
```

In the Bloomberg documentation are extremely woolly guidelines to meet the security criteria, saying:

> Allowed CAS permission for app portal apps:
>   1. IsolatedStorageFilePermission, Allowed="AssemblyIsolationByUser" UserQuota="2048000"
>   2. SecurityPermission, Flags="Execution, ControlThread, SerializationFormatter"
>   3. UIPermission, Unrestricted="true"
>   4. MediaPermission, Audio="NoAudio" Video="NoVideo" Image="SafeImage"
>   5. PrintingPermission, Level="DefaultPrinting"

The DLL which fails (we have the source for) has been renamed in the exception to "MyCustomDll.dll". This Dll does not use unsafe code or Platform Invoke, just .NET4.0 and WPF.

I wonder is there any way to test *why* this is failing by examining security permissions of the .NET assembly?

Comment: whats the version of the api you are using?

Comment: @Alechandro I don't have access to the API, its a client of mine. Turns out that they prevent all sorts, including unsafe code (understandable), but also reading from and writing to WriteableBitmap (not understandable)